# Using OCR to detect complex mathematical symbols

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to process some pdf files that contain equations in latex. I am using py-tesseract with eng+equ language, but it can't detect some math symbols like fractions, summations, and integrals from the pictures. It also adds some new characters to the results. This is the code I used to extract data. I can't share the images as they contain confidential data. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue? Note: I added the clean_text function to replace the long division bar that ocr is detecting as underscore before the dividend, which is not working.

```
import json
import PyPDF2
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2
import os
import re
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# Set the language to "equ" (equation) for OCR
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -l eng+equ'

def preprocess_image(image):
    # Convert PIL Image to NumPy array
    image_array = np.array(image)

    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding
    threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 10
    )
    return threshold

def clean_text(text):
    # Remove unnecessary spaces and newlines
    cleaned_text = text.replace("\n", " ")
#     # Replace long division symbol (_) with division symbol after the term
#     cleaned_text = re.sub(r'_\s*(\w+)\s+\((.+?)\)', r'\1/(\2)', cleaned_text)
#     cleaned_text = re.sub(r'_\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)', r'\1/\2', cleaned_text)
    return cleaned_text

def is_textual_image(image):
    # Convert image to grayscale if it has multiple channels
    if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] > 1:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray = image

    # Apply adaptive thresholding
    threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 10
    )

    # Calculate the percentage of white pixels in the image
    total_pixels = threshold.shape[0] * threshold.shape[1]
    white_pixels = np.sum(threshold == 255)
    white_pixel_percentage = (white_pixels / total_pixels) * 100

    # Calculate the percentage of non-zero pixels (non-textual regions) in the image
    non_zero_pixels = np.sum(threshold != 0)
    non_zero_pixel_percentage = (non_zero_pixels / total_pixels) * 100

    # If the white pixel percentage is above a certain threshold and non-zero pixel percentage is below a threshold,
    # consider it as a textual image
    return white_pixel_percentage > 10 and non_zero_pixel_percentage < 30  # Adjust the thresholds as needed

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    # Open the PDF file
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        # Create a PDF reader object
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

        # Find the start page of the introduction section
        introduction_start_page = 0
        for page_number, page in enumerate(pdf_reader.pages):
            text = page.extract_text()
            if re.search(r'Introduction', text, re.IGNORECASE):
                introduction_start_page = page_number
                break

        # Determine the range of pages to process (excluding introduction pages)
        start_page = introduction_start_page + 1
        end_page = len(pdf_reader.pages)

        # Get the first page and extract the title
        first_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

        # Extract the text from the first-page
        first_page_text = first_page.extract_text()

  
        # Find the title case words in the extracted text
        # title_match = re.search(r'\b(?!([A-Z]+\s)*[A-Z]+\b)[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+\b', first_page_text)       
        title_match = re.search(r'(?<!\S)(?:[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*)', first_page_text)

      
        if title_match:
            title = title_match.group(0)
        else:
            title = ""

        print(title)
        
        # Convert the PDF pages to images
        images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)

        # Extract text from each page
        result = []

        section_title = 'Introduction'
        section_text = ''
        print('Starting')
        

        for page_number, image in tqdm(enumerate(images[start_page:end_page], start=start_page), total=len(images[start_page:end_page]), desc='Processing Pages'):
            # Preprocess the image
            processed_image = preprocess_image(image)

            # Check if the image contains significant text
            if is_textual_image(processed_image):
                # Perform OCR using Tesseract
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_image, config=custom_config)
                # Compile the regular expressions
                # footer_pattern = r'^\d{0,9}/\d{0,9}-[A-Z0-9]+\s+[A-Z0-9]+\s+\|\s+\d{0,9}-\d{0,9}-\d{0,9}$'
                footer_pattern = re.compile(r'^.*-\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\S*')
                section_title_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+(\.\d+)*\s+')
                symbol_pattern = re.compile(r'«<')

                # Remove footer texts
                lines = text.split('\n')

                for line in lines:
                    # Check if the line is in the footer format and exclude it
                    if footer_pattern.match(line):
                        line = footer_pattern.sub('', line)
                        continue
                        
                    if symbol_pattern.match(line):
                        line = symbol_pattern.sub('', line)
                        continue

                    # Check if the line starts with a number and is in header format
                    if section_title_pattern.match(line):
                        
                        # Remove the leading number from the section title name
                        temp_section_title = section_title_pattern.sub('', line).strip()
                        
                        if temp_section_title == section_title:
                            section_text += ' ' + line  # Accumulate the lines of the same section
                        else:
                            # Store the previous title and content
                            section_text = clean_text(section_text.strip())
                            meta_data = {
                                'title': title,
                                'section': section_title,
                                'page_number': section_page_number  # Use the page number of the section
                            }
                            paragraph_data = {
                                'content': section_text,
                                'meta': meta_data
                            }
                            print(paragraph_data)

                            result.append(paragraph_data)

                        # Update the current title and subtitle
                        # section_title = line.strip()
                        section_title = temp_section_title
                        section_text = ''
                        section_page_number = page_number  # Update the page number of the section
                    else:
                        # Append the line to the current subtitle text
                        section_text += '\n' + line

        # Store the last subtitle and content
        section_text = clean_text(section_text.strip())

        meta_data = {
            'title': title,
            'section': section_title,
            'page_number': section_page_number
        }
        paragraph_data = {
            'content': section_text,
            'meta': meta_data
        }
        result.append(paragraph_data)

    return result

# Path to the PDF file
pdf_path = '0_key_performance_indicator.pdf'

# Call the function to extract text from the PDF
extracted_data = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)

# Save the extracted data as a JSON file
output_path = 'extracted_data_final.json'
with open(output_path, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(extracted_data, json_file, indent=4)

print('Extraction completed. Data saved to', output_path)
```

Comment: Have you tried `math` instead of `eng+equ` as `custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -l math'`?

Comment: No. I will try that.

Comment: @Sercan it didn't resolve the issue.